# Sending Form variables to a external page and get the html from server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I don't know if this is possible, what I want is just to get the html or the plain-text from the result of a form sent to a external page.

In this case, I have a form that send the variables to a external server and the result goes to the iframe, how I retrieve the html or text from the iframe? This is the correct way?

I'm trying to do this just to simplify a repetitive process here on my agency...

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="https://www.externalpage.com" target="iframe">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="0000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="b" value="0001" />
    <input type="hidden" name="c" value="0002" />
  <p>
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
<iframe name="iframe" scrollbars="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: Question is: What do you want to do with the result? Do you just want to display it to a user (somewhere else than in iframe) or do you want to process it by JavaScript or PHP? You've include PHP tag, but I don't see any PHP code.

Comment: I just want to make a .txt or .xml with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the tags you are using jquery

```
var myresult = $('iframe[name="iframe"]').html();
```

Should do the work.

//edit: just noticed the iframe is from an external domain, it might be subject to the same origin policy, in this case the above code might not work